# Getting an error as shown in below pic and not receiving any SMS

Tags: arduino, gsm, at-command

I am working on GSM900A module and Arduino Uno R3.
I am getting output as following while sending an SMS using AT commands:

```
AT+CMGF=1
Ok
AT+CMGS="+91 10digit mobile number"
message
ERROR
```

And SMS is not sent to the particular 10 digit number. How can I overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The format to send sms is:

```
AT+CMGS=<number><CR>
<message><CTRL-Z>
```

Please check if you have added the carriage return after your number.
Also, you have to wait for **>** symbol before you type the message. 
After the message is typed, give <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.
You can find the equivalent ascii or hex values for these in ascii table.

Answer (score 0):

amek sure there is no space between +91 and mobile number
I was also getting this errors because i did not enough power to gsm module. Make sure you are giving enough current. I think 2A should be fine